# MySQL Using a Variable LIKE '%Variable_Name%' in a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have this little simple trigger..

```
BEGIN

    DECLARE FILE_NAME VARCHAR(250);
    DECLARE FILE_REFR VARCHAR(500);


SET FILE_NAME = 'Foo';
SET FILE_REFR = 'Bar';

--- I'd like to execute the next statement, using variable FILE_REFR between %% in a LIKE clause:
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @num_rows FROM referers WHERE filename = FILE_NAME AND ref NOT LIKE "%FILE_REFR%";

...
...
...

END
```

Unfortunately, the variable name is not being picked up as a variable.. but as a CHAR, I know there is something missing there.

Help is more than appreciated.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the variable as:

```
CONCAT('%', FILE_REFR, '%');
```

So the complete select query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @num_rows FROM referers WHERE filename = FILE_NAME AND ref NOT LIKE  CONCAT('%', FILE_REFR, '%');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @num_rows
FROM referers
WHERE filename = FILE_NAME AND
      ref NOT LIKE CONCAT('%', FILE_REFR, '%');
```

MySQL does not find variables inside string literals.  Instead you have to use `CONCAT()` to piece the pattern together.